# WIndow preloader comes in delayed in jquery

Tags: jquery, preloader

Hi I am trying to add a preloader to my page, but what is happening is that the page loader is not loading when you enter the window.. It is waiting for the window to load, then it shows the loader as well.... how can I fix this? Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#all").hide();
var wh = $(window).height();
$("#loader").show();
$("#all").hide();
$("#loader").css("height",wh);
$("#loader").delay(4000).fadeOut(400);
$("#all").delay(4020).fadeIn(400);
});
```

So in short, first I can actually see the page then the loader comes in!!! I don't know how to fix this, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window.load` won't fire until the entire page is loaded. Try using [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/ may also be enlightening for you.

If `document.ready` still isn't early enough for you, make the loader show by default, then hide it at the point you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I would have written the code this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var wh = $(window).height();
        $("#all").hide();
        $("#loader").css("height",wh);
        $('#loader').show('slow', function() {
        $("#loader").delay(4000).fadeOut(400);
        $("#all").delay(4020).fadeIn(400);
      });
  });
```

This will first loads the page and will hide all but the custom loader on the page. Then rest you know. You could also use animate function to call a custom delayed loader.